# Thymeleaf - Use local variable in Collection Selection

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

On my page I have a list of reviews, and each review has some comments.
From my backend I get a list of all reviews, and a list of all comments.
Each comment has `review` property, which determines the review it belongs to.

Under each review, I am now trying to show the associated comments.
For this, I am trying to filter and loop over all comments from my `comments` list, where the ID of their parent review (`comment.review.getID()`) equals the ID of the current review (`review.getID()`).

This is how I am trying it, but it does not work.:

```
<div class="review" th:each="review : ${reviews}">
    <div class="review-comments" th:with="reviewID=${review.getID()}">
        <div class="comment" th:each="comment : ${comments.?[#this.review.getID() eq reviewID]}">
```

It throws this error:

```
Property or field 'reviewID' cannot be found on object of type 'de.firefuro.forum.entity.Comment'
```

So how can I compare the comment's review id with the local variable `reviewID` (or with the local `review.getID()`)?

I also tried

```
<div class="review" th:each="review : ${reviews}">
    <div class="review-comments">
        <div class="comment" th:each="comment : ${comments.?[#this.review.getID() eq review.getID()]}">
```

but that did not work either. it did not filter anything. Probably because it thought that with `review` i mean comment.review. I can't manage to use the local `review` variable.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Comment` class has `content` field, I guess this would be the right syntax:

```html
<div th:each="review : ${reviews}">
    <div th:text="${review.id}"></div>
    <div th:each="comment : ${comments.?[review.id == __${review.id}__]}">
        <div th:text="${comment.content}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, so double underscore means local variable?

Comment: @FireFuro99 not exactly: `__${review.id}__` is a _preprocessed_ expression that is evaluated _before_ comparison with `comment.review.id`. The complete syntax is `__${expr}__`, not just underscore.